# React: How to use setState in AddListener()?

Tags: reactjs, listener, bind, typeerror, setstate

I have a method that calls an addListener to data that does not exist yet until you've clicked on a button. However, as I try to set that data inside a state, I get the following error:

> TypeError: this.setState is not a function

I've tried binding my dataHandler like this:

```
this.dataHandler = this.dataHandler.bind(this)
```

yet it still returns this error. What am I forgetting here?

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        selActive: 4,
        loaded: false,
        mapInfo: ''
    }
    this.onScriptLoad = this.onScriptLoad.bind(this)
    this.dataHandler = this.dataHandler.bind(this)
}

dataHandler = (getJson) => {
    fetch(getJson)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(featureCollection => 
            dataLayer = map.data.addGeoJson(featureCollection)
        );
    map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
        map.data.revertStyle();
        map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {fillColor: 'blue'});
        // THIS IS WHERE I ADD MY SETSTATE. 
        // HOWEVER, THIS RETURNS AN ERROR ON HOVER
        this.setState({mapInfo: event.feature.countryNL})
    });
}
```

Comment: can you use `()=>` arrow function instead of `function(event)`

Comment: Thank you! This has also been advised by @HaiPham.

Comment: @CédricBloem sorry for missing explanation, I have updated my answer

Comment: @Hai Pham No problem! I noticed immediatly and read the docs :) Thank you for the information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript `this` always refers to the "owner" of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of.
Use arrow function instead.
An arrow functions doesn't have its own `this/super/arguments` binding. It inherits them from its parent lexical scope.

```
map.data.addListener('mouseover', (event) => {
    map.data.revertStyle();
    map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {fillColor: 'blue'});
    // THIS IS WHERE I ADD MY SETSTATE. 
    // HOWEVER, THIS RETURNS AN ERROR ON HOVER
    this.setState({mapInfo: event.feature.countryNL})
});
```

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Well, not exactly. `this` refers to the context of the function. If there is no context, then `this` presents a global object, yes, but if you are using function as event listener, for example, then `this` will reffer to the `currentTarget` of the event.

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance thanks for the information, I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

`this` inside a normal function either refers to the global object or the current instance (in case of being invoked via `new`). However `this` inside an arrow function is captured from the outer scope. So `this` inside that `addListener` callback refers to the global object (`window`). To solve this problem you have the following options:

- Using arrow function:

  ```
  map.data.addListener('mouseover', (event) => {
      map.data.revertStyle();
      map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {fillColor: 'blue'});
      // THIS IS WHERE I ADD MY SETSTATE. 
      // HOWEVER, THIS RETURNS AN ERROR ON HOVER
     this.setState({mapInfo: event.feature.countryNL})
  });
  ```
- Using [bound function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

  ```
  map.data.addListener('mouseover', function (event) {
      map.data.revertStyle();
      map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {fillColor: 'blue'});
      // THIS IS WHERE I ADD MY SETSTATE. 
      // HOWEVER, THIS RETURNS AN ERROR ON HOVER
     this.setState({mapInfo: event.feature.countryNL})
  }.bind(this));
  ```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I do not recommend you to use anonymous functions to be set as event listeners, because in this case you will not be able to `removeEventListener` or something simillar (probably, because it is not clear, what is the `map` here).

The second thing is that you should not bind your `dataHandler`, because it is already an arrow function, so there is no problems with `this` inside the `dataHandler` context. The thing that you should bind is your manual event listerer. So the result code should look like this:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        selActive: 4,
        loaded: false,
        mapInfo: ''
    }
    this.onScriptLoad = this.onScriptLoad.bind(this)
    this.dataHandler = this.dataHandler.bind(this)
    this.handleMouseOver = this.handleMouseOver.bind(this)
}

dataHandler = (getJson) => {
    fetch(getJson)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(featureCollection => 
            dataLayer = map.data.addGeoJson(featureCollection)
        );
    map.data.addListener('mouseover', this.handleMouseOver);
}

handleMouseOver(event) {
    map.data.revertStyle();
    map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {fillColor: 'blue'});
    this.setState({mapInfo: event.feature.countryNL})
}
```

or, using an arrow function, that is automatically being binded:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        selActive: 4,
        loaded: false,
        mapInfo: ''
    }
    this.onScriptLoad = this.onScriptLoad.bind(this)
    this.dataHandler = this.dataHandler.bind(this)
}

dataHandler = (getJson) => {
    fetch(getJson)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(featureCollection => 
            dataLayer = map.data.addGeoJson(featureCollection)
        );
    map.data.addListener('mouseover', this.handleMouseOver);
}

handleMouseOver = (event) => {
    map.data.revertStyle();
    map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {fillColor: 'blue'});
    this.setState({mapInfo: event.feature.countryNL})
}
```

Hope, this will help you! :)

Comment: It certaintly does help! Thank you!